# ₘ extensions vs line bundles over abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties

1. Given a complex polarized abelian variety $V$, we can define a map $$\operatorname{Ext}^1\left(V, \mathbb{G}_m\right) \to \operatorname{Pic}\left(V\right)$$
   by viewing an extension as a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor and sending it to the corresponding line bundle. Is there a description of the image of this map? Is there any restriction on the degree?
2. Will the answer change if $V=J\left(X\right)$ for a complex curve $X$ and we compose the above map with $$\operatorname{Ext}^1\left( \operatorname{Div}^0\left(X\right), \mathbb{G}_m\right) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1\left(V, \mathbb{G}_m\right)?$$ (In particular — is the last map an isomorphism?)

Comment: The answer to 1 is positive if you are using Yoneda Ext in the category of group schemes.  This might be a theorem of Rosenlicht.  For 2, what structure are you putting on $\text{Div}^0(X)$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\mathrm{Ext}^1(V, \mathbb{G}_m)$, not $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{G}_m, V)$?

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! Do you have a reference for the first claim? As for the second - I want view it as a functor from commutative rings to groups via addition of divisors

Comment: @JesseSilliman you're right! I'll edit it. Thanks!

Comment: To answer 1., the map is an isomorphism onto the degree zero line bundles. In the generality of arbitrary abelian schemes, this is known as the Barsotti-Weil formula (really, BW is stronger, asserting that this is an isomorphism of schemes, for an appropriate scheme structure on the ext group).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, I was reading $\text{Pic}$ as  $\text{Pic}^0$ based on the use in question 2.

Comment: What distinction is being drawn between $\operatorname{Div}^0(X)$ and $J(X)$ in part 2?

Comment: It is shown that $\mathrm{Pic}^{0}(A)\simeq\mathrm{Ext}^{1}(A,\mathbb{G}_{m})$ in Serre 1969
(Groupes algebriques...), VII, Sect 3, over a field, and over an arbitrary
base, in Oort 1966 (Commutative group schemes), III.18. (and many other places).